# Can't enable third screen on my laptop with hybrid nvidia / intel graphics on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, hybrid-graphics

I'm trying to enable a third screen on my laptop with hybrid graphics intel + nvidia with no luck. I'm using bumblebee to manage both cards.

In the graphical monitors configuration, the system, can see 3 monitors, I can get it working if I select mirroring monitors option but if try to select them as 3 independant desktops, this error comes up:

Failed to apply configuration: %s

If I try this xrandr command:

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --auto --right-of LVDS1
```

The error is:

xrandr: cannot find crtc for output VGA1

The output for xrandr --current:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3286 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+312 344mm x 193mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
DP1 disconnected
HDMI1 connected 1920x1080+1366+0 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080      59.9*+   60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1680x1050      59.9  
   1400x1050      59.9  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1440x576       50.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x576i       50.1  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   720x480i       60.1     60.1  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1  
VGA1 connected
   1366x768       59.8 +
   1024x768       75.1     72.0     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected
```

As you can see 3 monitors are connected althought the VGA1 is not working

Output for xrandr --listproviders:

```
Providers: number : 3
Provider 0: id: 0x2c2 cap: 0x1, Source Output crtcs: 0 outputs: 0 associated providers: 1 name:NVIDIA-0
Provider 1: id: 0x47 cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 3 outputs: 5 associated providers: 1 name:Intel
Provider 2: id: 0x47 cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 3 outputs: 5 associated providers: 1 name:Intel
```

I've tried with this X11 configuration:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    #Screen 0 "nvidia"
    #Inactive "intel"
    Screen      0  "Screen1" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen2" LeftOf "Screen1"
    Screen      2  "Screen3" RightOf "Screen1"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Asus"
    ModelName      "integrated"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 60.0
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor2"
    VendorName     "Hannspree"
    ModelName      "Hannspree"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor3"
    VendorName     "Acer"
    ModelName      "???"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Device1"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Screen  0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Device2"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Screen  1
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Device3"
    Driver "intel"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "SNA"
    Screen  2
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen2"
    Device         "Device2"
    Monitor        "Monitor2"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen3"
    Device         "Device3"
    Monitor        "Monitor3"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

But on reboot it always returns back to original one:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "intel"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "SNA"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No one? At this point, I think, any kind of solution to get 2 monitors connected to my laptop will be alright, even if it includes buying hardware...Restrictions are, the laptop, doesn't have a display port or USB 3.0.